# Group by and Join excludes one column in the output dataframe in Python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas, join, group-by

I have a dataframe with following columns.

```
col1   col2      col3   col4   col5    col6
A20    hghjfg    jhdf   A20.1  abcd    direct
A20    hghjfg    jhdf   A20.2  edfg    direct
A20    hghjfg    jhdf   A20.3  rtzu    direct
```

I would like to group by this dataframe and join unique values from other columns. I am expecting following dataframe

```
col1   col2      col3   col4                    col5                    col6
A20    hghjfg    jhdf   A20.1 | A20.2 | A20.3   abcd | edfg | rtzu      direct
```

I am using following python code to do this.

```
join_unique = lambda x: ' | '.join(x.unique())
df.groupby(['col1'], as_index=False).agg(join_unique)
```

However, when I do this only col1, col2, col3, col4 and col6 are in the output.

```
col1   col2      col3   col4                    col6
A20    hghjfg    jhdf   A20.1 | A20.2 | A20.3   direct
```

Why col5 is not there. How can I include it in the final dataframe.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

can you assign the result back to the dataframe

```
join_unique = lambda x: ' | '.join(x.unique())

df=df.groupby(['col1'], as_index=False).agg(
    join_unique
)

print(df)
```

Received below output:

```
 col1    col2  col3                   col4                col5    col6
0  A20  hghjfg  jhdf  A20.1 | A20.2 | A20.3  abcd | edfg | rtzu  direct
```